# Running Javascript Code on Different Site

Tags: javascript

I have a js code that works as i want. I am running this code only for a certain site. The link is clear. I write my js code in Chrome console and it works. This is everything.

I want to move this code to a new site. When I click the button on a new different site, I want to run javascript code on first site.

In short, Can I run javascript code on another site with the click of a button?
How can I do that?

Thanks for all the shares.

Comment: JavaScript runs in whatever page loads the script.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to write is a browser extension. It can be loaded into any site.

Comment: Is the website you want to run the script on yours or is it owned by a third party?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Socket.io to emit an event when you click on that button.
and on your other site, listen for that event and run the code as a callback.